# variadic methods: Check, if a argument is a typedef'ed block

Tags: objective-c

I created a veriadic Category method on NSArray to filter it into a dictionary with given blocks and keys

```
typedef BOOL (^TestBlock)(id element);
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryByFilteringWithBlocksAndKeys:(TestBlock)firstBlock, id firstKey,... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
```

Usage:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"aa", @"ab", @"cc", @"cd", @"dd", nil];
NSDictionary *dict = [array dictionaryByFilteringWithBlocksAndKeys:
                                    ^BOOL(id element) {return [element hasPrefix:@"a"];},@"a",
                                    ^BOOL(id element) {return [element hasPrefix:@"c"];},@"c", 
         nil];
```

It works quite good, but I wonder, how I can check, if a given block (other then the first) has the typedef'ed signature.

I get the blocks from the `va_list` with `TestBlock block = va_arg(args, TestBlock);`, but it also eats non-sense blocks like

```
NSDictionary *dict = [array dictionaryByFilteringWithBlocksAndKeys:
                                    ^BOOL(id element) {return [element hasPrefix:@"a"];}, @"a", 
                                    ^(id element) {;}, @"c", 
                          nil];
```

without complaining.

**Is there a way to check, if a block has the same signature as a typedef at runtime?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to check.   This would require new syntax in the compiler.  Effectively, you want "these arguments are optional/variadic, but must follow this type pattern".

Also note that treating a specifically typed argument list as a `va_list` is not technically correct, either.  It will mostly work by coincidence on most ABIs, but not all.  (Not that you are doing that, but it often comes up in these contexts).

> can you give me an example of what you mean with specially typed
>   argument list?

Sure, consider:

```
id objc_msgSend(id,SEL,...);
```

That is a var-args argument list.   Now, you might think you can do this:

```
objc_msgSend(mutableArray, @selector(addObject:), anObject);
```

But, technically, you can't.  varargs are not compatible with specifically typed argument lists, by the C spec.   Thus, you need to typecast:

```
void (*func)(id,SEL,id) = (void*)objc_msgSend;
func(mutableArray, @selector(addObject:), anObject);
```

That is, if the called API is *not* also varargs, then the call site must be compiled against a declaration of the call that has full argument type info...

Comment: can you give me an example of what you mean with specially typed argument list? my C-skills are limited. Thanks!